# Reading database names off a Server with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

Basically what I'm creating is a program that allows a user to read multiple database names from a server. I've hooked the server to the program and the connection works fine (some details are replaced with an * for security). However, I can't seem to get the database names to appear on the data grid view. Help?!

This is my work so far;

```
private void connectDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=***;Integrated Security=False;User ID=***;Password=***;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM sys.databases;"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        foreach(SqlDataReader read in reader)
                        {
                        int n = dataGridDataBase.Rows.Add();
                        dataGridDataBase.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = reader;
                        }
                    }

                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the SQLCommand object is not linked with the SQLConnection.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=***;Integrated Security=False;User ID=***;Password=***;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"))
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * FROM sys.databases;"))
{
      command.Connection = connection;//This is missing in your code.
      connection.Open();

      //Bind your datagridview to rows from the reader        
}
```

Comment: The .DataBind(); isn't working for me. An error comes up saying that there isn't a "definition for DataBind".

Comment: Remove that line of code.I assumed it to be ASP.Net.If it is WinForms then DataGridView doesn't have the DataBind() method.

Comment: Okay, I've removed it. However still nothing is showing up on the dataGrid. How can I get it to display the names of the databases in the server?